# Inject two objects of the same class with different fields using named in Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Suppose I have rectangle class implementing shape interface

```
class Rectangle @Inject constructor(private val id: String) : Shape {
    override fun info() {
        Log.d("Rectangle", "I am rectangle!, My id is $id")
    }
}
```

```
interface Shape {
    fun info()
}
```

One way of providing two objects of the same class with different id using @Named would be inside my module:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("Id1")
    fun provideId1(): Shape {
        return Rectangle("Id1")
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("Id2")
    fun provideId2(): Shape {
        return Rectangle("Id2")
    }
}
```

With that I can inject two rectangle objects in my mainactivity

```
    @Inject
    @field:Named("Id1")
    lateinit var rect1: Shape

    @Inject
    @field:Named("Id2")
    lateinit var rect2: Shape
```

However I would like my Module to look little bit different. Inside it I want to provide shape and using @named constructor parameters for objects. What I have is:

```
  @Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("Id1")
    fun provideId1(@Named("id1") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("Id2")
    fun provideId2(@Named("id2") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("id1")
    fun provideId1(): String {
        return "ABC"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("id2")
    fun provideId2(): String {
        return "XYZ"
    }
}
```

How can I achieve injection of two objects with different constructor parameters using such approach?

Comment: Different module to provide Rectangle with ID1 and ID2 ? then used as a dependancy in your main module?  What you currently have is just providing for ID1 and ID2 and a generic rectangle, but the link where those two things (IDs and Rectangle construction) is missing.

Comment: You're not really clear on why you're providing two strings, and a generic rectangle. How do you expect those two strings to end up in the rectangle's constructor? You provide two named strings, then use the same names for shapes in your main activity. That's not going to work.

Comment: Therefore I asked here what should I do.

Comment: Make a ShapeFactory, that will just spit out a Shape with the injected ID. inject the two strings in it, and it can provide two different shapes - with id1 and id2. then use those two modules as dependencies in your app module.

Comment: but you're missing the link where strings id1 and id2 get injected in the Shape's constructor. the shape itself needs a dependency on a module that provides those strings, or they need to be named "ShapeID1" and "ShapeID2" where they accept a named String parameter in their binding/providing module.

Comment: You can't provide a String named ID1 and try to use a Shape named ID1 - because the thing named that way isn't a shape, and there is no ID1 shape in the graph. the shape providing (or binding) module needs to take in the named strings and construct the shape itself. just use `@Named` in it's constructor.

Comment: Aha, i got it. They can't be in the same module. The reason is: while the module is being processed, it will provide named strings, but they will not be in the graph to meet the criteria for providing the rectangle-providing methods with those named parameters. You will need to move string-providing methods to a different module, and make your AppModule use it as a dependency. Then it should work.

Comment: Posted new answer, I *could* be wrong but it should work. I'm not sure that a single module can declare named dependencies to be used withing the same module though. Not sure though, as it doesn't really make sense why it shouldn't be able to work. However, you're missing the error you're getting - please post that as well.

Comment: Again, i would suggest moving the rectangle-providing methods to `RectangleProvidingModule`, keep the string-providing methods as `StringsProvidingModule` and make `AppModule` just use `RectangleProvidingModule` as it's dependancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key part you're missing:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("ShapeId1")
    fun provideId1(@Named("id1") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("ShapeId2")
    fun provideId2(@Named("id2") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }
}
```

the part that automates putting provided named strings into actual rectangle constructors.

however, i'd go with something simpler/cleaner like this:

```
RectangleNamed1Module.kt:

@Module(includes = [RectangleNamed1ProvidingModule::class])
internal interface RectangleNamed1Module {

    @Binds
    @Named("ShapeID1")
    fun bindRectangle(rectangle: Rectangle): Shape
}

@Module
internal object RectangleNamed1ProvidingModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideRectangle(
        @Named("id1") stringId: String
    ): Rectangle = Rectangle(stringId)
}
```

then you can just... copypaste this module as many times as you need and slightly change the named dependencies/parameters and thats about it.

You can use it as RectangleNamed1Module and RectangleNamed2Module, then just make those two modules a dependancy of your AppModule. and wherever you're trying to inject two shapes/rectangles named "Shape1" and "Shape2" should work, right?

Comment: This isn't quite correct though - the Providing module doesn't get to see the named string parameter this way. so it either needs to be provided in that ProvidingModule, or the module that provides the ID strings needs to be it's dependency. Take this just as a suggestion, not a working solution :D

Comment: Consider moving the `provides StringID1` into the individual RectangleProvidingModules and call it done, unless you need those strings elsewhere. If you do, extract the strings into a module of their own, and make that module a dependency of the RectangleProvidingModules.

Comment: It works only if I used  those RectangleNamedProvidingModules. Can I make it work using only AppModule?

Comment: @AdamHeinrich why do you want to use only one module? Is there a specific reason you're not sharing? Remember, you **want** to avoid bloated / godlike modules, and want to have (many) very small, single-purposed modules that provide exactly what is needed for a certain thing (e.g. feature) and nothing more, and nothing less. Whats the reason why you want to do it from just the AppModule? Maybe you could make it work using the AppModule alone; but you will need to show me how these named `Shape` objects are used in the app itself.

Comment: i create two objects named rect1,rect2 and call them using rect1.info(),rect2.info() in the mainactivity. 

The second solution you posted seems to complicated for me at the moment, this is why I asked.

Comment: oh. well... i've got good and bad news - good news: you don't have to do it that way. bad news: if you don't do it that way, somewhere down the line, requirements will change and things will get refactored and you will be sorry for not doing it that way :D in the end - whatever works for you, works. i just recommend the cleaner way, feel free to adapt however you see fit. @AdamHeinrich

Comment: But still the first snipped seems to fail. Why?

Comment: update your question with what you tried and the error you got.

Comment: Question editet.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment,

> Aha, i got it. I think. They can't be in the same module. The reason is: while the module is being processed, it will provide named strings, but they will not be in the graph to meet the criteria for providing the rectangle-providing methods with those named parameters. You will need to move string-providing methods to a different module, and make your AppModule use it as a dependency. Then it should work. However, this is just a best-effort guess

try something like this instead:

```
@Module(include = StringProvidingModule::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("Id1")
    fun provideId1(@Named("id1") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("Id2")
    fun provideId2(@Named("id2") id: String): Shape {
        return Rectangle(id)
    }
}

@Module
class StringProvidingModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("id1")
    fun provideId1(): String {
        return "ABC"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("id2")
    fun provideId2(): String {
        return "XYZ"
    }
}
```